# How to intercept toasts in Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

I'm working on an application that needs to react to pop-up toasts from another application (like Skype, Outlook Mail, etc.). Is it even possible? I was thinking of using:

```
public ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger(string applicationId)
```

to start background task. But I can't find a single word about what applicationId is and how to get an ID of, for example, Skype in my application. Any help would be much appreciated!